# Choose lines that minimize minimum distance from points

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, computational-geometry

### Problem statement

Given $n$ points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^p$, choose $m$ lines that minimize the sum of the squared distances between each point and the line closest to it. Assume $n \gg 2m$.

That is, find the lines that minimize

$$\xi = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i \in \mathcal{D}_j}^n \left|r_{ij}\right|^2$$

where $r_{ij}$ is the distance between $x_i$ and the $j$th line, and $\mathcal{D}_j$ is the list of indices of the points closest to the $j$th line.

I think the search space has dimension $(2p-1)m$, because each of the $m$ lines must be described by $p$-vector indicating the slope and another $(p-1)$-vector indicating the intercept with an arbitrary plane.

- Is there a clearer way to notate/formulate this problem?
- Is the problem convex?
- What is the dimension of the search space, and can it be reduced?
- How would you solve this problem?

### Ideas

**Principal component analysis:** In the $m=1$ case, the problem is [total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) regression. The optimal line is the line through the centroid and parallel to the eigenvector of the covariance matrix having the highest eigenvalue (the first "principle component").

For $m > 1$, a good guess would be to continue adding principle components, but this solution isn't optimal. Consider points arranged like these:

[image]

The first principal component is a diagonal line and the second principal component is orthogonal to that line, and $\xi > 0$. But we can achieve $\xi = 0$ by picking lines through the collinear points.

While the PCA lines aren't necessarily optimal, they might work well as seeds for an optimization routine that then varies the slopes and locations.

**Require that all lines be parallel, assume optimal slope is known:** Then it's just a matter of choosing multiple "centroids" through which the lines should pass, which reduces the search space to $(p-1)m$ variables. You could compute the projections of the points onto the space (whose dimension is $p-1$) orthogonal to the known slope, then use a clustering algorithm (e.g. $k$-means with $k=m$) to determine the centroids of the projections. Since optimal clustering (the facility location problem) is NP-hard, this suggests that the general problem is also NP-hard.

**Require that all lines be parallel and evenly spaced, optimal slope unknown:** Then there are even fewer variables: the slope, the placement of one line, and the spacing between it and the others. You could initialize the optimization process by picking the slope of the first principal component; then the residuals are 1-dimensional and the quantiles of their distribution can be used to pick evenly spaced offsets of the principal component line. Playing around, I think this problem is convex, but I haven't attempted to prove it.